# How stop the activity bar poping up when I debug in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I just want to stop the activity bar pop up when I run a file in vs code. Someone know how to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by activity bar? The panel on the left? Or Terminal / Debug Console?

Comment: if you drag it to its minimal size, it will still pop up but be less annoying (if I understand your problem correctly)